# Very long text in Oracle

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, special-characters, gateway

I would like to know which is the best practice for saving very long text in an ORACLE database field?

I save with Coldfusion from a form the text content of a mail in an Oracle database. I use currently the type LONG in my database field. I encounter problems for saving very long text (with many special characters like /, ", %, $, & and others) I receive an error 502 (Bad gateway). If the very long text contains some special characters it's not a problem.

Could you help me with that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Comment: have you looked at CLOB?  personally I have avoided LONG columns since the beginning - they are nothing but trouble

Comment: Oracle tells you [not to create new LONG columns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-F6309DF8-162F-48A4-9454-FEE59EC6644F). Use CLOB instead. But that isn't likely to be the issue with Coldfusion - sounds like an encoding problem.

Comment: `LONG` is deprecated for ages, I think there is no reason at all to use it. The list of restrictions for [LONG Data Type](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#sthref106) is quite long.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - of course, Oracle speaks out of both sides of its mouth when they tell us not to use `LONG`. (Which, of course, is the right advice.) **They** (Oracle), themselves, still use `LONG` and not `CLOB` in the data dictionary, for columns that are obviously of text type. They can make up any excuse they want, it doesn't change the fact that they aren't heeding their own advice. It's hard to fault users for following Oracle's own lead (even though, as we all agree, one **should not** be using the `LONG` data type).

Comment: "Bad gateway" doesn't sound like a problem Oracle would have with special characters to a `LONG` column (or any other data type). The error is a networking error, but it MAY be caused by code "around" the Oracle code. Seems like a ColdFusion issue (or issue with your own code if you wrote any - say in PHP).

Comment: @mathguy check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834964/why-long-data-type-has-been-replaced-by-lob-in-oracle why oracle still using long

Comment: @Moudiz - Not really. That answer explains why Oracle still has the `LONG` data type available in current versions (so that they don't break OTHER PEOPLE's upgrading to new versions from old ones). I have no problem with that. It absolutely does not explain why Oracle itself still uses this data type in the data dictionary. Surely they could control the conversion from LONG to CLOB in their own schema! It probably costs them "too much" to do so, and they don't care that because of that, there are some queries we can't write on the data dictionary tables.

Comment: @mathguy Because "other peoples" code regularly queries the data dictionary.  For every person saying we should ditch LONG, there is someone that will be screaming "you broke my code!" if we do.

That's why (for example) we generally add new columns to try improve functionality.  For example, DBA_VIEWS now has the additional TEXT_VC column to supplement the TEXT long column.  I would have preferred this new column to be a clob, but we do our best to accommodate both groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CLOB` column in the database.

Use bind parameters in ColdFusion to insert the value.

```
<cfquery name="insert_long_text" datasource="your_datasource_name">
INSERT INTO your_table(
  id,
  email
) VALUES (
  <cfqueryparam value="#your_id_value#"    cfsqltype="CFL_SQL_INTEGER" />,
  <cfqueryparam value="#your_email_value#" cfsqltype="CFL_SQL_CLOB" />
)
</cfquery>
```

Or pass the values (again using bind parameters) to an Oracle stored procedure.

If the message is particularly long and loading it into memory is going to create performance issues then you may need to use Java (which ColdFusion is built upon) to stream the file [(example streaming BLOBs)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44161721/1509264).